# Will my NZ permanent residency be cancelled if I renounce my Indian Passport

Tags: new-zealand

I am an Indian Citizen holding a Green Card. I plan to apply for American Citizenship, and I have to renounce my Indian Passport when I do that.

The thing is, I am a permanent resident in New Zealand and I can live/work in New Zealand Permanently and indefinitely. When my Indian passport is cancelled, my Indefinite NZ visa will also be cancelled! How can I travel to NZ?

Comment: Yes I am permanent resident in New Zealand and I can live/work in New Zealand Permanently. The advantage of New Zealand Permanent Residency is indefinite - you can live and work anytime!I have a valid visa but my passport will be cancelled. I am thinking is this will be an issue ?

Comment: Generally, jurasdiction specific, a residence permit will become invalid if the conditions underwhich it is issued. Your permit was issued as an Indian citizen. That condition has changed. Depending in NZ law, it may become invalid. In Germany it would become invalid.

Comment: @Midavalo India requires it.  The asker of the question will lose Indian citizenship automatically by operation of law at the moment of naturalization.

Comment: @phoog American law also requires you to renounce any citizenships you might possess when you naturalize, as well. It doesn't look like NZ does, though, so he could possibly become an American citizen and then an NZ citizen, if he wanted to and he meets the requirements to become an NZ citizen.

Comment: @nick012000 I thought those are just words in the oath and explicitly not required in law.

Answer (score 4):

*(**NOTE**: The OP updated their question to state they are a PR in NZ so this answer no longer covers the question asked. As there is no other answer, and there is useful information in the comments for this answer I'm not going to delete it - but the answer isn't isn't valid after the edits as it is referring only to a NZ tourist/business visa, not a PR)*

As a US Citizens you will not require a visa to travel to New Zealand for stays of up to 3 months.

You will need to apply for an New Zealand Electronic Travel Authority (NZeTA) once you have received your US Passport, and then you will be able to travel to New Zealand without the need for a visa.

Comment: Thank you for your Comments! But I have to hold my Permanent Residency in New Zealand where I can live and work indefinitely. If I renounce my indian passport I don't if my PR will be cancelled.

Comment: You are adding details that you didn't include in the original question. Are you a permanent resident in NZ or the USA?  You can't be both...

Comment: In that case I think it's probablly time to talk to a NZ immigration specialist. I don't know about NZ in particular but I do know that in some countries permanent residence can be lost if you live outside the country too long and/or no longer intend to live their permanently. Telling NZ that you have naturalised as a US citizen could draw their attention to the fact you are no longer living in NZ.

Comment: Doc, it's not necessarily true that a person can't have PR status in both countries at once.  It depends on the conditions governing the lots of that status as set out in the law of each country.  As @PeterGreen's comment could imply, it's possible that this person has already lost PR status under NZ law.

Comment: @phoog Looks like you can't lose your PR status in NZ that way. https://www.immigration.govt.nz/knowledgebase/kb-question/kb-question-1091

Comment: After fulfilling certain residency conditions, New Zealand issues an indefinite PR visa without (almost) any string attached, usually only revoked for serious issues like national security or criminality.

Answer (score -1):

If it is a permanent resident visa without conditions, your visa should not be cancelled **even if your nationality changed** and your passport is cancelled. But you will need to apply for a transfer of eVisa with details of your new, valid US passport.

https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/already-have-a-visa/transferring-my-visa-to-a-new-passport

---

> **64 Cancellation of visa on triggering event**
>
> (1) A visa is cancelled in the following circumstances:
>
> - (a) on the deportation of its holder from New Zealand:
> - (ab) on the day after the first date on which a deportation order may be served on the person under section 175A, whether the visa was
>   issued before or after this paragraph came into force:
> - (b) on the refusal of entry permission to its holder:
> - (c) on entry permission granted to its holder being revoked:
> - (d) if the holder arrived at an immigration control area,— (i) on the holder leaving the immigration control area without presenting
>   himself or herself to an immigration officer; or (ii) on the holder
>   failing to comply with the instruction of an immigration officer to
>   remain in the area:
> - (e) if the holder arrived at a place other than an immigration control area, on failing to present himself or herself in the
>   prescribed manner and within the prescribed time as required under
>   section 103(1)(b):
> - (f) on the start date of a further visa granted to its holder:
> - (g) on the grant of New Zealand citizenship to its holder:
> - (h) on the registration of New Zealand citizenship by descent under section 7(2) of the Citizenship Act 1977 by its holder:
> - (i) on the issue of an evidentiary certificate under section 21 of the Citizenship Act 1977 that confirms the holder is a New Zealand
>   citizen.

http://legislation.govt.nz/act/public/2009/0051/latest/whole.html

A change of nationality does not create a deportation liability (fraud, forgery, character, crimes, security etc.) nor form any ground to refuse entry permission (provided the visa is transferred).

Comment: I think the point of the question isn't that the passport is cancelled, rather that the citizenship used to apply for and obtain the PR is revoked.  Does this answer cover that situation?

Comment: @Midavalo I was trying to say that the PR status is not related to the passport, although the current passport details are recorded.